# Pandas dataframe: uniformly scale down values when column sum exceeds treshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Initial Situation

Consider the following example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [3., 2., 1., np.nan],
    'B': [7., np.nan, 1., 3.],
    'C': [4., 5., 1., 2.],
    'D': [1., 0., 2., 3.]    
})
```

which in printed form looks like:

```
     A    B    C    D
0  3.0  7.0  4.0  1.0
1  2.0  NaN  5.0  0.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
3  NaN  3.0  2.0  3.0
```

### Desired Result

I would now like to do the following for each column of this dataframe:

1. Calculate the sum of the column's values (ignoring any NaN values).
2. If the sum exceeds 10.0, then I want to uniformly scale down all values in the column such that the new sum is exactly 10.0 (again ignoring any NaN values).

Basically I'd like to obtain a result dataframe that looks like this:

```
     A         B         C    D
0  3.0  6.363636  3.333333  1.0
1  2.0       NaN  4.166667  0.0
2  1.0  0.909091  0.833333  2.0
3  NaN  2.727273  1.666667  3.0
```

### Tried thus far

The following code obtains the desired result.

```
def helper_func(s):
    if s.sum() > 10.:
        return s * 10. / s.sum()
    else:
        return s

result_df = df.apply(helper_func)
```

However this code feels a bit verbose and inefficient to me. Based on my experience with pandas thus far I'd suspect that a more vectorized solution is still possible. Would anyone be able to help me find this?

Comment: Well first of all, you're calculating `s.sum()` twice if `s.sum > 10`. Save that value to a variable. Although, to solve your less verbose problem you could use a lambda function `df.apply(lambda s: s*10 / s.sum() if s.sum() > 10 else s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
thres = 10
result = df * thres / df.sum().clip(lower=thres)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method:

```
colSums = df.sum()
df / ((colSums * (colSums > 10) / 10) + (colSums <= 10))
```

Here, we create a variable with the summed value for each column, then the denominator checks if the sum of the column exceeds 10 adjusts those colums so that they sum to ten. Those columns whose sums less then 10 are incremented to 1 so that we are not dividing by 0. The resulting array is then divided across the columns. This returns the desired result.

```
Out[46]: 
     A         B         C    D
0  3.0  6.363636  3.333333  1.0
1  2.0       NaN  4.166667  0.0
2  1.0  0.909091  0.833333  2.0
3  NaN  2.727273  1.666667  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this result dataframe seems to look different than my desired result dataframe. Doesn't it?

Comment: @Xukrao I missed the summing to 10 in my first read. The method has been adjusted to fit this criterion.

Comment: @Trenton_M I missed the summing to 10 in my first read. The method has been adjusted to fit this criterion.