# Is there a faster method to calculate implied volatility using mibian module for millions of rows in a csv/xl file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

**My situation:**

The CSV file has been converted to a data frame `df5` and all the columns being used in the for loop below are of `float` type, this code is working but taking many many hours to just do `30,000` rows.

**What I want from my situation:**

I need to do the same operation on millions of rows and I am looking for fixes/alternate solutions that make it considerably faster.

**Below is the code I am using currently:**

```
for row in np.arange(0,len(df5)):         
    underlyingPrice = df5.iloc[row]['CLOSE_y']
    strikePrice = df5.iloc[row]['STRIKE_PR']
    interestRate = 10
    dayss = df5.iloc[row]['Days']
    optPrice = df5.iloc[row]['CLOSE_x']
    result = BS([underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,dayss], callPrice= optPrice)
    df5.iloc[row,df5.columns.get_loc('IV')]= result.impliedVolatility
```

Comment: The way to make this code much faster is to make `BS()` operate on vectors instead  of scalars, thereby eliminating the outer `for` loop over rows which is dead slow.  Are you willing to reimplement the `BS()` function?

Comment: Could you add a small example of your input dataframe (just something like 10 data rows) and your desired result dataframe (like in [this equestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57650114/7306999))? This will greatly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: BS function belongs to Mibian module, and this function uses a goal seek feature. What do you suggest should i make the function myself using numpy and pandas because numpy list are not checked for data type whereas in the above code, python will check the datatype all the time as long as there are the number of rows.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your loop seems to take values from each row to build another column `IV`.
This can be done much faster by using the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method, which allows to use a function on each row/column to calculate a result.
Something like this:

```
def useBS(row):
    underlyingPrice = row['CLOSE_y']
    strikePrice = row['STRIKE_PR']
    interestRate = 10
    dayss = row['Days']
    optPrice = row['CLOSE_x']
    result = BS([underlyingPrice,strikePrice,interestRate,dayss], callPrice= optPrice)
    return result.impliedVolatility

df5['IV'] = df5.apply(useBS, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the post, however, even the apply method seems to take forever i think. I think using numpy and pandas here would do the job, but i have no clue how to implement it, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, apply _is_ pandas. This is the fastest method that comes to my mind to replace a `for` loop on a dataframe rows. If it takes a lot, maybe the problem is elsewhere. As suggested in the comments, you may try to vectorize the `BS` function, whatever it is (and may be indeed this function which is slowing down the execution). But let me say that there is a limit to optimization: if you have a really big dataframe, at some point you just need to accept that the execution will take some time.

Comment: BS function belongs to Mibian module, and this function uses a goal seek feature. What do you suggest should i make the function myself using numpy and pandas because numpy list are not checked for data type whereas in the above code, python will check the datatype all the time as long as there are the number of rows.

Comment: I just had a quick look at the code of Mibian `BS`. That class has loops inside, so I think is that which require time. It does not seem easy to be vectorized. Depending on your experience, you can try to reimplement it, but even if you manage to do it, I don't think you are going to save a lot of time. I'm afraid you cannot do a lot here, just use the `apply` method (still better than a `for` loop). Measure the execution time of `apply` using ~100 rows to have an idea of how long is needed to calculate the whole dataframe and see if it is acceptable.

Comment: Valentino, thank you for your valuable advise. So if its difficult to vectorise Mibian BS function in Python, is it possible to implement it on C++ and use it in python ?

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert, so... yes, anything is possible. But to me seems even more complex. If you are more confident in C++, you can try. Have a look at the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/extending/extending.html) to know how to extend python with C++ code. Or at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43387112/wrapping-c-code-with-python-manually) post.